react native ios adds localhost to the start of the backend root Api url
So when I run the project in Android I don't have any issues, when I run it as ios the backend URL changes to https://localhost/domain.com
I couldn't find from there the localhost gets added. ( this is only visible on xcode debug console) on react native console the URL is correct.
but all axios calls get NetWork Error
